# How To Fix Pop/Crackling Audio When Playing Samples Sequentially C#

Tags: c#, audio, .net-core, console, naudio

The context:
A simple .Net Core 3.1 console app.
I'm attempting to play audio generated programmatically, from a string dictating a sequence of notes (duration and frequency), using sine waves to emulate a 'retro' sound, and also for simplicity.
I've used two methods for this, and both produce the same problem.

Method 1:
Use the `System.Console.Beep(int frequency, int duration)` repeatedly. This produces a 'pop' or 'crack' between every note played. There was also a small delay in playback that was undesirable, and I went searching for another method.

Method 2:
Using a proper audio library this time round; NAudio, I used the `SampleGenerator` to create `ISampleProvider`s in a List<> and then submit them into a `ConcatenatingSampleProvider` and then creating a `WaveOutEvent`, initialising it with the CSP and playing it like so:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Tunes are formatted as such in 120BPM: "#8ths Note Octave Dash" e.g. "4A3-2C4-4re-"
  /// </summary>
  public static async Task PlayTune(string tune) =>
     await Task.Factory.StartNew((tune) =>
     {
        var t = (string)tune;
        List<ISampleProvider> sampleProviders = new List<ISampleProvider>();

        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i += 4)
        {
           int.TryParse(t[i].ToString(), out int d);
           var note = t[i + 1].ToString() + t[i + 2].ToString();

           if (note == "re")
              sampleProviders.Add(new SignalGenerator() { Gain = 0.0 }.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000.0 / 8.0 * d)));
           else
           {
              sampleProviders.Add(new SignalGenerator() { Gain = 0.2, Frequency = GetFrequency(note), Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin, }
                 .Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000.0 / 8.0 * d)));
           }
        }


        var ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

        using var wo = new WaveOutEvent();
        wo.Init(new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(sampleProviders));
        wo.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>((obj, args) => { ewh.Set(); });

        wo.Play();

        ewh.WaitOne();

     }, tune);
```

This, while creating better sound and getting rid of the slight delay between notes the Console had, still had the same issue with a pop/crackle between each sample within the CSP.
I found nothing online of similar issues, and looked into some of the generic "fix crackling Windows 10" to no avail.

With my current setup, some audio will cause a little bit of crackling, but this is very rare and in nuanced cases such as with a certain game. Usually there is no problem. Using Windows 10 Home, no dedicated soundcard (whatever is built into the Gigabyte Aourus Elite AM4 mobo), Realtek Audio, Headphones.

How do I fix/remove the popping?

**UPDATE:**
As was recommended below, I added fade in/fade out effects to the samples to attempt to mitigate an issue with 'unclean samples'. Here's the current code:

```
 public static async Task PlayTune(string tune) =>
     await Task.Factory.StartNew((tune) =>
     {
        var t = (string)tune;
        var sampleProviders = new List<DelayFadeOutSampleProvider>();
        var durations = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i += 4)
        {
           int.TryParse(t[i].ToString(), out int d);
           var note = t[i + 1].ToString() + t[i + 2].ToString();

           if (note == "re")
           {
              var fifosp = new DelayFadeOutSampleProvider(new SignalGenerator() { Gain = 0.0 }.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000.0 / 8.0 * d)), true);
              sampleProviders.Add(fifosp);
              durations.Add(1000.0 / 8.0 * d);
           }
           else
           {
              var fifosp = new DelayFadeOutSampleProvider(new SignalGenerator() { Gain = 0.2, Frequency = GetFrequency(note), Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin, }
                 .Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000.0 / 8.0 * d)), true);
              fifosp.BeginFadeIn(2);
              sampleProviders.Add(fifosp);
              durations.Add(1000.0 / 8.0 * d);
           }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleProviders.Count; i++)
        {
           using var wo = new WaveOutEvent();
           var ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
           wo.PlaybackStopped += (sen, args) => ewh.Set();
           wo.Init(sampleProviders[i]);
           wo.Play();

           Thread.Sleep(10);
           sampleProviders[i].BeginFadeOut(durations[i] - 15, 1);

           ewh.WaitOne();
        }
     }, tune);
```

This ended up helping a lot, there was a large distortion at the start of the samples that got cleared up easily, but there's a small blip at the end to that (depending on the note) is a louder pop. I tried both sleeping the thread manually and using the provided fade-out, and using a custom SampleProvider I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861290/applying-a-linear-fade-at-a-specify-position-using-naudio), neither method worked no matter how much I cut off.

Any ideas as to the nature of this?

Comment: My guess is you won't find anything specifically for windows 10 as this is a pretty common problem with audio programs. What's your system details; ram and cpu?

Comment: Also, pops at the beginning and end of a note can be that the sample isn't clean. If you were creating your own sounds you could do a sharp fade at the beginning and end that is unnoticeable to the human ear but will help with some popping.

Comment: 8GB 2666mhz RAM (overclocked to 2800 possibly, I forget). AMD 3200G for cpu.

Comment: The sharp fades actually sound like a pretty good idea, I'll have to try that out a bit later. Can't now unfortunately, will update when I do.